# After Brexit - Partner visa for American girlfriend of an Italian living in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, italian-citizens, brexit

My girlfriend is American, I'm Italian and I'm living in the UK.

I met my girlfriend at the end of March 2015, we started living together from the 1st of July 2015. A few months ago she had to move back to the States and so we're seeing each other every 2/3 months.

Would she be able to get a **Partner Visa** in the UK this year, **after Brexit**?

When could we apply for it? Do we have to wait for the date stated on the first proof she has that states that she was living at my same address?

And how long would it take to get this kind of visa?
I read around the internet that it could take from a few weeks to several months (and that the price increased of 25% this year). Any more precise estimate?

Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is a bit of an unknown at the moment. See the link in the comment above.

Comment: Well my question is more focused on the Partner Visa but yes good info there too, thanks

Comment: The UK won't allow immigration sponsorship for unmarried unregistered partners until they've been living together for two years. You may not be able to qualify unless you marry or register. Regardless, Brexit will almost certainly not be completed this year, and not before 2019.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you're right: http://www.immigrationboards.com/immigration-for-family-members/unmarried-partner-visa-but-living-separately-t108380.html. If you add your answer I'll mark it as chosen one.